# Execution Plan - Hash vs. Merge in sql vs. Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I've got a problem with a terribly performing stored procedure.  The odd part is that if I run the procedure it takes hours.  If I run the contents of the procedure as a batch in ssms, it runs in a reasonable amount of time.  I have narrowed the problem to a single statement within the proc.

My first thought was a bad query plan cache.  However adding WITH RECOMPILE to either the proc, or OPTION(RECOMPILE) to the offending statement within the proc made no difference.

So I captured the (actual) execution plan from both exec-ing the procedure and running the statements directly and found this difference:

The slow stored procedure version has a `<Merge ManyToMany="True">` element in the xml whereas the plain sql version has a `<Hash>` element.

I don't think I know enough about execution plans to determine why it would choose one or another.

Both versions were run on the same data -- etc:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
exec myproc; --capture plan
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SQL Statements from procedure -- capture 2nd plan
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

What sorts of things can influence the plan within a procedure that would be different when executing directly from ssms?  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to narrow this down further?

I don't know how much help the particular query is here, but it's a MERGE statement:

```
MERGE schema.UpdatableView FORUPDATE
USING
 (
    large select statement that's not part of the problem
 ) DATA
ON DATA.field = FORUPDATE 
WHEN MATCHED THEN  -- 50% of the cost is here
    UPDATE SET
      LOTS of field updates
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN -- other 50% is here
   INSERT (FIELDS)
   VALUES (FIELDS
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
;
```

The updatable views may be part of the problem, but SQL Profiler doesn't seem to think so.  The underlying INSERT and UPDATE triggers on the view aren't begun until after the statement has been running for a few hours, and they complete in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: How many rows in the underlying tables? Have you updated statistics recently/ever?

Comment: Roughly 40-50K rows in the table being updated, and about the same amount in the USING subclause.

Comment: Statistics appear up-to-date on the underlying tables.  However, SSMS is not showing any statistics on the updatable view.  Does this matter?  And why would that give different data between a stored procedure and plain sql execution?

Comment: I'm not sure, just thinking out loud, since the plans are different, obviously there is something only being considered by one version of the plan (and one thing might be cardinality). Can you put the actual plans somewhere so we can compare them?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I'm not sure I'm legally allowed to post the real plans, and it would take some time to obfuscate it.  I'll see what I can do.

Comment: You mentioned 50% cost for update and 50% cost for insert.How the join type comes into picture? Also,You have mentioned in question "The slow stored procedure version has a <Merge ManyToMany="True"> element in the xml whereas the plain sql version has a <Hash> element." Is that element part of the merge statement or is it somewhere else in the procedure?Are these instead of triggers or after triggers on the updatable view?

Comment: @GulliMeel, I'm not sure how well I can explain this, but...The execution plan is mostly the inner SELECT statement for the data.  In the graphical plan in ssms, that query feeds into an icon that represents the 'ON' clause (the expression is easily identifiable).  That feeds two subsequent "Nested Loops" which pull in a "Clustered Index insert" on the updatable view.  Those Clustered Index insert nodes are the ones listed as 50% of the cost.

Comment: then issue could be related to the insert and update.Is cost of insert and update are same for proc as well as adhoc sql ? instead of triggers means the inserts will happen on some other table and not the updatble view's underlying table.Also, can you try one thing inside proc instead of merge statement just join the updateable view with statement within using and see how that performs.

Comment: Attaching sql profiler to the process indicates that the underlying triggers are performing well.  They don't begin until after the lengthy delay.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually due to different runtime settings like `ANSI_NULLS` and `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`. I suggest you recreate the stored procedure and the views in the same SSMS tab (same session) that you use to test the query. This will make sure that both use the same settings. I think you will notice that both use the same plan.